# Appveyor problem - R package stringi can't be installed

Tags: r, r-package, appveyor, stringi

Lately the build with Appveyor does not work any more. It fails before actually building the program, because somehow the package *stringi* can't be installed.

Locally everything works fine, but I need a workaround for Appveyor.
Has anybody a solution on how to fix this?

This is the error message on Appveyor:

> - installing *source* package 'stringi' ...
>     ** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     *** arch - i386
>     c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"c:/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_ICU_settings.cpp -o stri_ICU_settings.o
>     /bin/sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++: No such file or directory
>     make: *** [stri_ICU_settings.o] Error 127
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package 'stringi'
> - removing 'c:/RLibrary/stringi'
>     In R CMD INSTALL
>     Error in i.p(...) : 
>     (converted from warning) installation of package 'stringi' had non-zero exit status
>     Calls:  ... with_rprofile_user -> with_envvar -> force -> force -> i.p
>     Execution halted
>     Command exited with code 1

See also:
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/frehbach/eventdetectr/builds/19569698

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this by adding

```
USE_RTOOLS: true
```

to your `appveyor.yml` ([see here](https://github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor)).

The issue is that since you don't have any code that needs compiling, AppVeyor doesn't install Rtools, but compiling `stringi` obviously requires Rtools; see line 40 of the [build log you linked to](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/frehbach/eventdetectr/builds/19569698):

```
== 10/17/2018 06:33:11: Skipping download of Rtools because src/ directory is missing.
```

Using the AppVeyor setting mentioned above will force the installation of Rtools anyway.